# Regex Match End of Line Unless it Ends with a Closed Bracket

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write a JavaScript Regex that will grab the end of a line unless said line ends with a closing bracket, example:

```
[word]
lengthy text line

[other word]
even lengthier text line! Whoo!
```

That part I have down pat writing up this Regex `new RegExp(/[\n]\n|(?![^\]])$/gm)`

But I also need to be able to grab the end of the line even where there isn't a double space, and that is proving to be SUPER difficult since I don't really know a ton about Regex.

```
                                        --   [word]
These two lines need to be grouped      --   lengthy text line

                                        --   [other word]
These two lines need to be grouped      --   even lengthier text line! Whoo!
This needs to be it's own group         --   This text line is the longest of them all!
                                        --   [more words]
These two lines need to be grouped      --   The last guy can win...
```

What's annoying is that there is a very simple Regex that accomplishes this goal, but it's not currently supported in FireFox, and that's a problem. `(?<!])\n` Negative Look Behind Assertion

EDIT: The method used for the information is splitting, it splits the value placed into a textarea and matches it to `array[i].match(/^\[(.*?)\]\n/)`.  It'd look something like this:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/[\n]\n|(?![^\]])$/gm);
var array = $('#textar').val().split(regex);

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var match = array[i].match(/^\[(.*?)\]\n/)
}
```

but with a lot more code taking those variables and using them.

SOLUTION:
Wiktor Stribiżew had the solution. Changing .split(regex) to .match(regex) and adding their regex fixed the problem

```
var regex = new RegExp(/^.*[^\]\n](?:\]\n.*[^\]\n])*$/gm);
var array = $('#textar').val().match(regex);

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var match = array[i].match(/^\[(.*?)\]\n/)
}
```

Comment: You have forgotten to indicate what final result you need, what method you are going to use the pattern in. I guess it is splitting, so all you need is `text.match(/^.*[^\]\n](?:\]\n.*[^\]\n])*$/gm)`

Comment: the method used is splitting, it splits that value placed into a textarea and matches it to `array[i].match(/^\[(.*?)\]\n/)`

Comment: I mean it, you need to use `String#match`, not `String#split`, since you want to avoid the lookbehind.

Comment: YES! CHANGING .split() TO .match() MADE IT WORK!  I have been bashing my head against a wall for hours and days trying to figure this out!

Comment: I posted the solution with explanation below.

Comment: 'even where there isnt double space' yes ? elaborate please. wish i culd tell what problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `String#match`:

```
text.match(/^.*[^\]\n](?:\]\n.*[^\]\n])*$/gm)
```

**Regex details**

- `^`  - start of a line
- `.*[^\]\n]` - 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible and then a char other than a newline and `]`
- `(?:\]\n.*[^\]\n])*` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - `\]\n` - `]` and a newline, LF, char
  - `.*[^\]\n]` - 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible and then a char other than a newline and `]`
- `$`  - end of a line.

See the JS demo:

```js
var text = "[word]\nlengthy text line\n\n[other word]\neven lengthier text line! Whoo!\nThis text is the longest of them all!\n[more words]\nThe last gyu can win...";
console.log(text.match(/^.*[^\]\n](?:\]\n.*[^\]\n])*$/gm));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a regex like this:

```
/^\[.+(\n+[^\[]+)/gm
```

- `^` at the begining of the string,
- look for `[`
- `.+` followed by any character
- `(\n+[^\[]+)` an enter any number of times or any character as long as it is not `[`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/c1giqu/3

For your convenience, the full match keeps the text between brackets. The first group includes only the text without the brackets.

Comment: This seems to collect the whole phrase rather than just grabbing the end of the line like regex that I posted does. The script that runs the regex splits the code into an array like ["[word]↵lengthy text line", "", "[other word]↵even lengthier text line! Whoo!"] NOTE: The blank space in the middle is caused by the double space, which gets ignored when ran.